# How to reference an object's property that was declared in main method in a different class

Tags: java, object

I have 2 classes in 2 separate files. My first class in Person.java is shown below:

```
public class Person(){
    String name;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person paul = new Person();
        paul.name = paul();
    }
}
```

How would I reference that ^ specific person object's name property (paul) in my second class: Family.java's main method? Inside of Family.java I've tried creating a new person object but i can't then reference the Person object, Paul,'s name property.

Pretty much in Family.java

```
public class Family(){
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
```

inside of the main method i want to get the paul object, which i created in Person.java's main method,'s name property

Comment: A program only has one [*entry point*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entry_point). And `paul.name = paul();` is gibberish.

Comment: `Person()` and `Family()` is not correct java syntax. It should be `Person` and `Family`.

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done. Upon `Person.main` returning, `paul` falls out of scope and is no longer accessible, and becomes eligible for garbage collection.

You could instead do something like this:

```
public class Person{
    String name;
    static Person paul;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        paul.name = "Paul"; //I assume you meant this?
    }
}

public class Family{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person paul = Person.paul;
    }
}
```

But judging from what you're trying to do (and that you ahve two main methods) you may have a deeper issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can have `static member` in your `Person` class then access in the `Family` class. You can define the `getter` for the `name` attribute for getting the name of the `Person`. Also you can keep both the class in one file, keeping only one of the class public, because file name should same as the public class. Also `()` are not required for declaring a class. As `name` is `String` type in the class, you can define an string literal for assigning to it.

```
public class Family {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Person person = Person.paul;
    String name = person.getName();
  }
}

class Person{
  private String name;
  static Person paul;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    paul = new Person();
    paul.name = "paul";
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }    
}
```

**PS :** What are you trying to achieve with this code? Because `two main method` are not required. You can define an `constructor` in the `Person` class with an `String` argument. Create the `Person` object in you `Family` class as you need.